Whitelabel Error Page
Estoy practicando con el lenguaje Java, Spring, SQL(postgres) y JSP
pero al correr mi el codigo main, en la consola todo sale bien, pero al intentar abrir al url me sale el error

estas son las dependecias q tengo en mi archivo pom.xml
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Web para aplicaciones web RESTful y servidor embebido -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Driver para PostgreSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Lombok para evitar código repetitivo como getters/setters -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencia para pruebas -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jasper para soportar JSP en Tomcat embebido -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Implementación de JSTL para JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

estas son las carpetas y archivos

y esto es lo q tengo en mi aplication.properties
spring.application.name=demo
# Conexion postgresql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/empleados_db

spring.datasource.username=postgres

spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# Evitar que se cree el esquema de db

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

server.servlet.context-path=/demo

La ruta en la q estan los archivos jsp y html estan bien, asi q no se por q sale ese error

Ya logre resolver el problema, las carpetas estaban mal, y tenia versiones antiguas. cambie eso y ya me funciono bien.

JSP no se lleva bien con Spring Boot embebido por defecto. Si sigues teniendo problemas, considera cambiar a Thymeleaf como motor de plantillas, ya que se integra mejor con Spring Boot.

Hola Iván, entiendo.
Gracias por la respuesta
